# how to query last image of 5 album by yii active record

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii

I use Yii framework to develop a website, I want to know how to get the last 5 images orderd by create_time but not within the same album by using Yii active record and by plain SQL.

here's my albums table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_album` (
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `album_folder_name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55 ;
```

and here's my images table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_image` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_album` (`image_album_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

please note that I use "create_time" for sorting images.

Again, I need a query to get the last 5 images orderd by create_time but not within the same album by Yii active record and plain SQL.

for example the last 7 images are:

```
a.jpg in the album 7
b.jpg in the album 5
c.jpg in the album 7
d.jpg in the album 6
e.jpg in the album 3
f.jpg in the album 4
g.jpg in the album 2
h.jpg in the album 1
```

I need the query result to be like the following:

```
a.jpg in album 7
b.jpg in album 5
d.jpg in album 6
e.jpg in album 3
f.jpg in album 4
```

not like the following:

```
a.jpg in album 7
b.jpg in album 5
c.jpg in album 7
d.jpg in album 6
e.jpg in album 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  a.album_name,
  i1.image_name
FROM tbl_album a
INNER JOIN tbl_image i1 ON i1.image_album_id = a.album_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT image_album_id, MIN(image_id) image_id
   FROM tbl_image
   GROUP BY image_album_id
) i2  ON i2.image_album_id = i1.image_album_id 
     AND i1.image_id = i2.image_id
ORDER BY a.album_name DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The `JOIN` with:

```
   SELECT image_album_id, MIN(image_id) image_id
   FROM tbl_image
   GROUP BY image_album_id
```

will insure that for each album, the first image will be returned. Therefore you will got only one image for each album, then `LIMIT 5` will limit the result set to be only 5 albums.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c9a/4)

**Note that:** The `ORDER BY` clause will determine which five albums will be returned by the `LIMIT 5` clause. So don't expect that the albums are returned in the way they are stored as the expected result in your question, because records in the table has no specific order. They are stored as a set, and you have to specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your query to get them in a specific order.

---

**Update:** IF you are looking for the last created image for each album, use the `MAX(creaet_time)` instead like so:

```
SELECT
  a.album_name,
  i1.image_name,
  date_format(i1.create_time, '%Y-%m-%d') create_time
FROM tbl_album a
INNER JOIN tbl_image i1 ON i1.image_album_id = a.album_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT image_album_id, MAX(create_time) LatestCreateTime
   FROM tbl_image
   GROUP BY image_album_id
) i2  ON i2.image_album_id = i1.image_album_id 
     AND i1.create_time = i2.LatestCreateTime
ORDER BY i1.create_time DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/279f9/4)

---

**Update 2:** For the duplicate values, use the `DISTINCT` keyword, or you can use the `MAX(image_id)` instead, since the `image_id` is autoincremental, like so:

```
SELECT
  a.album_name,
  i1.image_name,
  date_format(i1.create_time, '%Y-%m-%d') create_time
FROM tbl_album a
INNER JOIN tbl_image i1 ON i1.image_album_id = a.album_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT image_album_id, MAX(image_id) LatestId
   FROM tbl_image
   GROUP BY image_album_id
) i2  ON i2.image_album_id = i1.image_album_id 
     AND i1.image_id = i2.LatestId
ORDER BY i1.create_time DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15dc/7)

Comment: it give me this error:Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.image_name
FROM tbl_album a
INNER JOIN tbl_image i1 ON i1.image_album_id = a.al' at line 3. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT
a.album_name
i2.image_name

Comment: @diaaf - Sorry it was a missing `,` after `a.album_name`. See my edit.

Comment: thank you  very much for your help, i need to order it by image create_time not the album_name, can you help me?

Comment: @diaaf Do you mean in the final result set or to get the last created image  for each album?

Comment: i need the last 5 images in tbl_image but in the result if there is two images in the same album then ignore the second image and get image from another album, did you get it?

Comment: @diaaf My query will give you only one image per album you will ever get two images in the same album thats what I did in my query. But the question is that which image to return for each album? Currently the query I posted will give you the first one, the one with the min image_id, is that true? Or you are looking for the last one by create time? Thanks.

Comment: i am looking for the last image by create time :) thank you very much for your patience

Comment: @diaaf You're welcome any time. See my edit, and don't hesitate to ask if this not what you are looking for, or if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I find another solution to my question!

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_image 
WHERE image_id IN (SELECT MAX(image_id) 
                   FROM tbl_image 
                   GROUP BY image_album_id) 
ORDER BY create_time DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

It gives me the same result, Without use inner join which reduce performance,
What your opinion about this solution?

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60aa8/4)

Comment: It is the same as the other solution with the `INNER JOIN` the predicate `IN` works the same. May be this is simpler. But you will also need to `JOIN` with the albums table.

Comment: معلومات كثيرة تعلمتها منك اليوم، الله يجعلها في ميزان حسناتك، أتمنى أن يتكرر الحديث بينا مجدداً، بارك الله فيك وتصبح على خير أخي :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what it returns,

```
select m.image_name,a.album_name
from tbl_album a inner join
tbl_image m on a.album_id=m.image_id
group by m.image_name,a.album_name
order by 2 LIMIT 5
```